# Wrong duplicate

Tags: discussion

There are many questions regarding a buggy kernel being mis marked

This is another duplicate of [Kernel panic after update to 4.4.0-108-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-1-10-2018-update-to-16-04) being mis marked as [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Examples :

[Booting problem black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994140/booting-problem-black-screen)

[Kernel panic after update to 4.4.0-108-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic)

I flagged both questions, but please take the time to look at why and what we are marking as a duplicate so users needing support can be guided to the proper solution.

Thank you

Comment: The situation was changing rapidly yesterday. When I first flagged https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic and some other questions, I was not aware something special was happening. The flags cannot be retracted as of now. What should I do? Should I remove the generated comment?

Comment: @Melebius no, it is fine, I was just bringing a new development to everyone's attention in the midst of a new problem with kernels. I think now at least we know where to send people for support and that is the point. Thanks for looking.